# Read .pages files in Windows

Tags: windows, pages

I used a Mac from about 2008 to 2012. I uploaded .pages files on to Dropbox and have since lost access to this Mac, but I have access to the Dropbox where the files are. I am currently using Windows 10 and would like to read these on my Windows machine.

However, all the fixes I've looked up seem to rely on viewing some kind of Preview.pdf by converting the .pages to a .zip. My machine actually auto downloads these .pages files off dropbox as a .zip automatically, however in the QuickLook folder there's only a thumbnail.jpg. No preview. Aside from that there's some kind of index.xml.gz and Pkginfo. Is there any way to be able to read this old file?

Comment: There is a web version of Pages at icloud.com which you can normally access from a Windows browser, but exactly how you could use it with dropbox I'm not sure.  And pages formats have changed several times so your old ones may not be openable with the currrent apps anyway.

Comment: I believe the web version will allow you to upload Pages Documents. Have you tried that?

Comment: See the onward link and explanation in [this related Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256393/136150).

Answer (score -2):

Well, it's not exactly a solution, more of a workaround, but Google Docs now read .pages files and will in many instances be able to show the contents. It depends on what version and how complex the .pages documents are.

The current version of Pages will be able to open Pages '09 files if you have a Mac owning friend.

Thirdly, if you rename the file extension to zip, and unzip them, you will see a preview of the contents that can be of some use to you.

Comment: Did you not read the 2nd paragraph of his question, where he says he already unzipped it but could NOT find a previw?  You should delete your Thirdly.